# Cannot set the current time of the audio element using Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel-8, html5-audio

I've read up and used quite a number of solutions including 'canplay' or oncanplay. But everytime i try to drag the slider in the progress bar and set the current time, the current time will always be 0

Here is my code, i really wish someone can enlighten me with regards to this topic.

Do note that this file is a .blade.php file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Simple Audio Player with jQuery</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>HELLO</p>
    <h1>Simple Audio Player with jQuery</h1>
    <audio id="audio" controls>
        <source src="{{ asset('v2/music/rain.mp3') }}" type="audio/mpeg" preload="auto">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
    <div id="progress-container">
        <input type="range" id="progress" min="0" max="100" value="0">
    </div>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            // Get references to the audio element and progress bar
            var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
            var progress = document.getElementById('progress');
            var isSeeking = false; // Add a flag to track seeking

            // Add an event listener to update the progress bar as the audio plays
            audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
                var currentTime = audio.currentTime;
                var duration = audio.duration;
                var progressValue = (currentTime / duration) * 100;
                progress.value = progressValue;
            });

            // Add an event listener to seek when the progress bar is changed
            progress.addEventListener('change', function() {
                var progressValue = progress.value;
                var duration = audio.duration;
                console.log(progressValue);
                console.log(duration);
                var newTime = (progressValue / 100) * duration;
                audio.currentTime = newTime;
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The two console log values of duration and currentTime are as follows

1        @ line home:43

157.8267 @ line home:44

88       @ line home:43

157.8267 @ line home:44

Comment: Is the media available at the time you're trying to change the `currentTime`? The `duration` property can return `NaN` under [certain circumstances](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/duration) which would mess up your calculations

Comment: Hi , thanks for taking interests in my queries, yes the media is available. So what would happen is, i would click the play button, the music starts playing but when i drag the slider either to the end or start , as soon as i call audio.currentTime, the audio will reset to 0 again.

Comment: `duration` is a finite number. So below are the results
home:43 1
home:44 157.8267
home:43 88
home:44 157.8267

i clicked twice so , duration value is 157.8297